# How to serialize class with polymorphic property using micronaut-serialization and annotations?

Tags: kotlin, jackson, micronaut

I followed this [guide](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-serialization/1.0.0/guide/index.html) to use Micronaut Serialization with Jackson annotations.
When I create an abstract `Base` class and a `Derived` class, I can use `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` to correctly serialize objects of the `Derived` class.

However, when I serialize an object of `OtherClass` with a property of type `Base` but with runtime type `Derived`, the property is serialized as `Base`.

The code below should explain my problem. Note that I am using `io.micronaut.serde.ObjectMapper`, when I replace it with `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` it works as expected.

Is there a way to make it work using annotations?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo
import io.kotest.core.spec.style.ShouldSpec
import io.kotest.matchers.string.shouldContain
import io.micronaut.serde.ObjectMapper
import io.micronaut.serde.annotation.Serdeable
import io.micronaut.test.extensions.kotest.annotation.MicronautTest

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "class")
@JsonSubTypes(JsonSubTypes.Type(Derived::class))
@Serdeable
abstract class Base(val baseProperty: String = "baseProperty")

@Serdeable
class Derived : Base()

@Serdeable
class OtherClass(val otherProperty: Base)

@MicronautTest
class SerializeTest(objectMapper: ObjectMapper) : ShouldSpec({
    should("serialize Derived") {
        val derived: Base = Derived()
        val valueAsString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(derived)

        /**
         * succeeds:
         * valueAsString = "{"class":"com.example.Derived","baseProperty":"baseProperty"}"
         */
        valueAsString shouldContain "class"
    }

    should("serialize otherProperty as Derived") {
        val derived = Derived()
        val otherClass = OtherClass(derived)
        val valueAsString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(otherClass)

        /**
         * fails:
         * valueAsString = "{"otherProperty":{"baseProperty":"baseProperty"}}"
         * expected: valueAsString = "{"otherProperty":{"class":"com.example.Derived","baseProperty":"baseProperty"}}"
         */
        valueAsString shouldContain "class"
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Micronaut Serialization but have used [classical Jackson for Kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) with `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` and this works properly for a top object or embedded object like you have in `OtherClass`.

In one of my use cases, it took me a long while to find this attribute being necessary on the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation:

```
visible = true
```

So I am not claiming this as a solution, but the `visible` attribute documentation says

> Default value is false, meaning that Jackson handles and removes the type identifier from JSON content that is passed to JsonDeserializer.

So perhaps this is relevant so the inner object's type is not wiped for view higher up in the object graph??

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Actually, I am getting a compiler error when adding `visible = true`. I clarified my post. When I use the `ObjectMapper` provided by Jackson, it works as expected.

Comment: looks like it's not supported by Micronout